# phpexcel - using array functions

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel (http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/, https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)

I have to use array function for my calculations in Excel. For example:

```
=SUM(IF(D4:D7+G4:G7,1,0))
```

If I would write the formula manually I should press Ctrl+Shift+Enter when I finish writing the formula.

If I set the value using the following code:

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2,10,"=SUM(IF(D4:D7+G4:G7, 1, 0))");
```

I get the `#VALUE!` in B10 cell, because Ctrl+Shift+Enter wasn't press to set the formula to be array formula.

What is the way to do it with PHPExcel? I tried even to set:

```
$sheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(2,10,"{=SUM(IF(D4:D7+G4:G7,1,0))}");
```

but it doesn't help (it prints the formula as a text `{=SUM(IF(D4:D7+G4:G7,1,0))}`).

Thank you!

Remark, I use the current version of PHPExcel I downloaded on 2-July-2013

Comment: Probably you've already found this [post on PHPExcel's forum](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/286378). It's been a full year and a half since then, maybe [Mark Baker](http://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker) will have something new to add to it by now.

Comment: Array functions are not supported by PHPExcel 1.x - the Calculation engine is currently being rewritten for the 2.0.0 release specifically to provide support for array functions as well as a few other features that aren't yet supported